# Encrypting ConnectionString for SQL Unit Tests in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: unit-testing, azure, encryption, azure-sql-database, azure-keyvault

I have a number of SQL Unit Tests written in Visual Studio 2015. Currently they connect to the database (a SQL Azure Database) using static connection strings in an app.config file.

I would like to protect this information using Azure Key Vault if possible.

I have seen articles such as [this one](https://kamranicus.com/posts/2016-02-20-azure-key-vault-config-encryption-azure) and [this one](https://eren.ws/2014/02/04/encrypting-the-web-config-file-of-an-azure-cloud-service/) on encrypting a web.config file but they seem more geared towards azure web apps.

Could anyone provide some implementation recommendations more closely suited to a SQL Unit Testing scenario or confirm that the above approaches would work in my case?

Or is there another solution such as overriding the ExecutionContext which is used by the TestService?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you found this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53tyfkaw(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I don't think storing SQL connection strings for unit tests in Key vault is the way to go. For your unit tests to retrieve these connection strings from Key vault, [it needs a token from Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-use-from-web-application#authenticate-with-a-certificate-instead-of-a-client-secret) to talk to Key vault. So you'd need to register an application in Azure AD that has permissions to retrieve secrets from Key vault.

But for your application to authenticate to Azure AD as that registered application, it needs a *client id* and a *client secret*. This client secret obviously cannot be stored in Key vault, so you're back to square one with a secret you need to store outside of Key vault.

If your unit tests always run on the same machine, you could install a client certificate and use that to authenticate with Azure AD instead of the client secret. But this would make your unit tests not very portable.

Your probably better off to store your connection strings in a private config file that you exclude from source control and [reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa903313(v=vs.71).aspx) from your `app.config` or `web.config` file, or read them in environment variables.